# SQLAlchemy delete() function flushes, but does not commit, even after calling commit()

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a **flask** app that uses **sqlalchemy** to read, write a **postgres** schema. When i use the `.delete()` function, it only flushes, but actual changes to the database do not occur.

```
Session = (sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False,bind=conn))
sess = Session()
sess.query(Table).filter(Column.id==1).delete()
sess.commit()
```

I tried without `scoped_session`, but still the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

You're overwriting sess with the number of deleted rows, and then trying to commit that number to the database. The .delete() method returns the number of rows to be deleted (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete).

Additionally, you set autoflush=False when you created your session. That makes it so you have to explicitly flush to the db after a commit. I suggest this:

```
Session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, bind=conn)
sess = Session()
rows_deleted = sess.query(Table).filter(Column.id==1).delete()
sess.commit()
print str(rows_deleted) + " rows were deleted"
```

Comment: Whoops. Thats not what I was actually doing, fixed the code snippet to reflect what I am actually doing.

Answer (score -1):

```py
db.session.query(Model).filter(Model.id==123).delete()
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. As part of that, it would be useful to include how this improves upon the existing answer.