# Can't commit with MySQL/InnoDB after delete?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using [sqlservice](https://pypi.org/project/sqlservice/) with sqlalchemy to connect with a MySQL database and I can do everything I need except delete and commit. I've turned SQL_ECHO on and I see the DELETE but the COMMIT is never made (even doing it explicitly).

Example:

```
db.Table.filter_by(item_id=item_id).delete()
db.commit()
```

The closest related question I could find was here: [SQLAlchemy delete() function flushes, but does not commit, even after calling commit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405800/sqlalchemy-delete-function-flushes-but-does-not-commit-even-after-calling-co)

I have verified the delete is on the correct id, the query is returning the expected results, and delete is returning the correct number of rows. I have even tried explicitly flushing before/after commit.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hey Travis, I've had the same type issues. could you give a little more context?

Comment: @brddawg I think I just solved this using `destroy`. Check out the example at the end of **Quickstart** on the sqlservice page I linked to.

Comment: not sure why you wouldn't use the commit() function...you could change the autocommit to true, or another setup. also looks like you're trying to deduplicate based on item_id and that doesn't look like a method that will work...let me know where you're at

Comment: try db.session.commit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment,

Under the **Quickstart** section on https://pypi.org/project/sqlservice/:

```
Destroy the model record:
db.User.destroy(user)
# OR db.User.destroy([user])
# OR db.User.destroy(user.id)
# OR db.User.destroy([user.id])
# OR db.User.destroy(dict(user))
# OR db.User.destroy([dict(user)])
```